# jquery date picker display exceeding page scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery.datePicker.js for my date picker icon in jsf 1.1 . when my calendar Icon is placed at the extreme right of the page, and when clicked on the icon, more than half of the calendar pop-up is unable to be displayed because the page's width is only finite.

the pop up work fine on rest of the page, only it doesn't get displayed properly if its placed at the right edges because the calendar displays to the right of the icon.

what should i do to make it display to the left, in such scenarios.

any help or suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in an Angular bootstrap app a while ago. I fixed my issue by targeting the desired datepicker with CSS and changing its positioning.

For example, in my angular app, I had a datepicker set up like this:

```
<div class="calendar-box">
    <input ng-model="split.shipDate" min-date="split.shipDateMin" max-date="split.shipDateMax" ng-click="dateOpen($event, split, 'shipDateOpened')" type="text" datepicker-popup="{{model.datePickFormat}}" is-open="split.shipDateOpened" ng-change="setCancelDate(split)" ng-readonly="true">
    <i class="calendar desktop" ng-click="dateOpen($event, split, 'shipDateOpened')"></i>
</div>
```

Then I targeted this specific calendar using the parent class and then the bootstrap datepicker class of .dropdown-menu as follows:

```
.calendar-box .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

(Where .dropdown-menu is angular-bootstrap's datepicker class)

You can modify the positioning as you please.

Though I am unfamiliar with the jquery datepicker, I checked the source code and it appears as though its class is '.ui-datepicker'

Thus, if this is the case, you can do the same thing by using:

```
.parent-class .ui-datepicker {
     /*Some sort of positioning here*/
}
```

Otherwise, use your dev tools to inspect the datepicker and try to figure out which jQuery class is setting its positioning.